# Is there a language with the speed of C/C++ but without buffer overflows and has a garbage collector?

Tags: programming-languages

I am looking for a programming language that is fast like C and C++ and has a garbage collector and is not prone to buffer overflows. I am looking for something between Java/C# and C/C++. Is there such a language?

Comment: Can you put some more details as where in C/C++ the speed advantage is please? Java and .net are JIT compiled and may be comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for buffer overflows and collecting garbage has a cost: if you need these features, then you will *not* get the speed of C/C++. Tradeoff.

Java and C# are very, very close to C++ speed in *most* types of applications, so unless you need something very specific, I suggest you go with one of those 2 languages.

If you just want a garbage collector for C++, [you can get one here](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29). It's a compiled language with most of the features from C++ in addition to garbage collection and some others.

Answer (score 2):

Language "speed" is highly application dependent.  The JVM is darn fast for certain kinds of code--hot spot can actually be faster than native code.  On the other hand, functional style and a good optimized can let you get good performance with less code--often Haskell apps are as fast in practice as ones in C.

For a real cross of Java/C# and C++ the best place to look is the D language.  It has garbage collection, and optional access to `malloc` and `free` and even inline assembly for C level performance.  It has enough safety to be less prone to buffer overflows, but you can still have them.  http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/index.html

You can always garbage collect C/C++, but it will cost you. Java, Haskell, ML, even Python can use garbage collectors that know what values might be pointers, so are faster than using a collector for C, C++, or D.